# Custom UICollectionViewLayout: layoutAttributesForElementsInRect asks for really little rect

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I've created my custom layout subclassing `UICollectionViewLayout`. It works exactly as I need but when the collection has only a little number of elements (like "3") the method `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` asks information for a rectangle with `0 width`.

This is the code of my layoutAttributesForElementsInRect implementation:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect{

    NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes in self.elementsAttributes) {

        if(CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, attributes.frame)){
            [results addObject:attributes];
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

I cache the attributes in the `prepareLayout` method... so for example I have 3 elements, but the `rect` parameter that I receive from the previous function is just "impossibile", indeed it is: `{{0, 0}, {0, 180}}`.

This happens only when I have a few cells in my collection view.

Why and how to get attributes for all the cells that should be displayed?

Answer (score 6):

The problem was in the override of `collectionViewContentSize`. I had a bug in this function and with a small number of Cells it returns a width of 0.